# How to use FILTER to return a range with no blanks

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have one sheet called 'Recetas' which has as first row a list of names. There are some blank cells between each one.

[image: one sheet called 'Recetas' which has as first row a list of names. There are some blank cells between each one.]

In my main sheet I want to generate a range with those names without the blank spaces.
I have tried to use `=FILTER(ARRAYFORMULA(Recetas!$1:$1), ARRAYFORMULA(NOT(ISBLANK(Recetas!$1:$1))))` but it displays an #ERROR! saying there is an issue with the formula.

As the documentation says, the first argument should be a range and the second one should be a column/row or in my case an ARRAYFORMULA.

I have checked both arguments in isolation and both work but when I use them in the formula, it doesn't work and the error message doesn't specify what is the problem.

[image: Proof of both first arguments working but the formula giving an error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try:

```
=torow(Recetas!1:1;1)
```

- could be your sheet locale uses `semicolon` convention

Comment: It was the semicolon convention. I don't use sheets often and forgot about this.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need `ARRAYFORMULA()` to filter. Try the following formula-

```
=FILTER(Recetas!$1:$1,Recetas!$1:$1<>"")
```